# Observing Properties of a User Defined Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I kind of know that we cannot observe properties of an object by simply observing an object. But I want to know if my understanding is correct.

Can we do something like this ?  http://jsfiddle.net/Z3gNC/

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

$(function () {
    var vm = (function () {
        var person = ko.observable(new Person("ABC", 23));
        return {
            person: person
        };
    })();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

It is not working so we can't I guess. I also don't understand where this character 'c' comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated your fiddle to be the more-usual KO pattern:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z3gNC/1/

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.age = ko.observable(age);
}

$(function () {
    var vm = (function () {
        var person = new Person("ABC", 23);
        return {
            person: person
        };
    })();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

The reason you see 'c' in your original fiddle is because vm.person is a ko.observable function, which when minimised looks like:

```
function c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.Ka(d,arguments[0])&&(c.P(),d=arguments[0],c.O()),this;a.k.zb(c);return d}
```

Every function has a name property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

so in this case vm.person.name is the name of the function vm.person which when minified is 'c' !

---

Edit: if you use a single observable Person, KO won't know that the inner property changes, unless you tell it with a valueHasMutated call. This next demo uses your VM structure and binds the changes in the textbox to the span, via a change event and a valueHasMutated call. So it works, but the 'pure' KO approach above is perhaps preferable for simplicity.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z3gNC/6/

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

$(function () {
    var vm = (function () {
        var person = ko.observable(new Person("ABC", 23));
        var mutate = function(data, event) {
            data.person.valueHasMutated();
        }
        return {
            person: person,
            mutate: mutate
        };
    })();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

... which needs this HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value:person().name, event: {change: mutate}" />
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works but we are observing the properties on our own. So we can not observe the properties of an object by simply observing the object ? Is this a correct conclusion ? Also, what if the 'Person' type is defined in some other file and we cannot observe the properties . What do we do then ? I somehow wanted the track  changes to the name and age properties by observing the object itself.

Comment: Sure, and you will need an extra valueHasMutated call to tell KO that the inner properties have changed - here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3gNC/5/

Comment: Thanks again. So after every 2  seconds you are checking if the value has changed, right ?

Comment: That was just a demo really... I just added another edit with a 3rd example that does more what you want, which is to link the textbox to the span with valueHasMutated ... so when you type in the textbox, the span will be updated via the change event which calls valueHasMutated. It's a bit ugly - the pure KO approach is much tidier - but it does work!

Comment: you obviously know this in and out. Thank you. So we have to do something extra to observe properties. Simply observing the object does not work. Either make the properties observable or use the mutate method, right ?

Comment: Exactly, well-summarised :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're not far off, you just need to unwrap your `person` observable when referencing it in your markup:

### [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3gNC/3/)

```
<input data-bind="value:person().name" />
<input data-bind="value:person().age" />
```

**Edit from comment**

### [Update JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3gNC/4/)

You can make the properties of `Person` observable so that they track changes like so:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.age = ko.observable(age);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This gets the initial values in the text boxes but does not update then spans once I change the textbox values. Does this mean we cannot track properties ?

Comment: You need to make them observable in that case, I will update the fiddle, but it's similar to the other answer.